# Removing from ListBox inside of a Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
ObservableCollection<String> listBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<String>();
scheduledRecordingListBox.ItemsSource = listBoxItems;

public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    listBoxItems.Remove(itemToBeRemoved);
}
```

Just a snippet of what I'm actually trying to do. I believe the error is caused because the timer is running on a different thread than the GUI main thread that the ObservableCollection I'm trying to remove from is.

Comment: *I believe the error is caused because the timer* **What is your Error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the Trick:

```
public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBoxItems.Remove(itemToBeRemoved)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WinForms, then just use the [System.Windows.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class. It's [Tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event is automatically executed on the UI thread.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. On the Tick event it calls timerElapsed and if a condition is true I want to remove an item in listBoxItems from the listBox. For some reason it's not allowing that in the timer.tick. I looked up the specific error and others with similar problems were solved using a dispatcher but I'm not really sure how to use one in this case or why that is necessary. I'll post the specific error when I have it in front of me a little later.

Comment: You haven't specified the specific error yet. And you haven't indicated yet if you're using WinForms.

Comment: WPF. Sorry I don't have it in front of me right now, I'll post it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.invoke.aspx) it executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

You can also have a look of the section timers in this [page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx)